# JavaFX canvas strange errors

Tags: java, javafx

I am using javaFX canvas and i update the painting every 1 second or more frequently if i am dragging the mouse over it.

[image]

Although i am in **JavaFX** **thread** i get these strange errors:

1)`java.lang.InternalError: Unrecognized PGCanvas token: 67
    at com.sun.javafx.sg.prism.NGCanvas.renderStream(NGCanvas.java:1157)`

2)`java.lang.ClassCastException: com.sun.prism.paint.Color cannot be cast to java.lang.String`

3)Something an error for `miter>1`

Most times it work well but others it just doing its own things.

> What is causing this errors?

Answer (score 0):

I also had this error. In my case, I drive an audio generating application which draws an oscillogram into a canvas. The audio generators are running in a separate thread:

```
Platform.runLater(() -> {
  // Main Loop
  Thread t1 = new Thread(() -> {
    while (running) {
      try {
        double sample = generator.pullNextSample();
        oscRT.putSample(sample);
        output.write(sample);
      } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
      }
    }
  }, "Engine Thread");
  t1.start();
});
```

Most times it runs without issue, sometime the odd exception occurs and the window content is broken.

Comment: This code does not make much sense. If you are creating a new thread anyway, then why do you wrap that in a Platform.runLater() call? You don't say what your code inside the thread is doing but if it is manipulating the scene graph, then you should wrap that in a Platform.runLater() call.

Comment: oscRT.putSample draws in the canvas. The other code is realtime Audio which should be performed in a separate thread. I wanted to wait until the javaFX Scene is initialized before starting the thread. This mostly works, but seems not to be good practice. Now I changed the code so that only this statement is surrounded by Platform.runLater.